# Spinner in a PyGObject Gtk.TreeView does not spin

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygobject, gtktreeview

It is not clear for me how to use `Gtk.SpinnerCellRenderer` in a `Gtk.TreeView` with a `Gtk.ListStore` as model.

In this example the spinner is shown but it is *inactive*. It doesn't spin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class TreeView(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        # model
        self.model = Gtk.ListStore.new([bool, int])
        for i in range(5):
            self.model.append([random.choice([True, True, False]), i])

        # view
        Gtk.TreeView.__init__(self, self.model)

        # column bool (as spinner)
        self.spinner_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererSpinner.new()
        col_bool = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('bool',
                                      self.spinner_renderer,
                                      active=0)
        self.append_column(col_bool)

        # column int
        col_int = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('int',
                                     Gtk.CellRendererText(),
                                     text=1)
        self.append_column(col_int)


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Mein Gtk-Fenster')
        self.set_default_size(100, 120)

        self.view = TreeView()
        self.add(self.view)

        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can make your program as simple as possible. 1, five rows aren't necessary. 2, Use a single class. Anyway, I have a minimum working example, https://gist.github.com/mywtfmp3/1d50c8f722b0f2729c7adaf61e06dc06. You need to increase "pulse" value of cellrendererspinner, and do increment repeatedly with `GObject.timeout` function.

Comment: I thought it is a MWE. Please give me an example of a PyGObject based MWE. Maybe you can edit my question. I don't see how to make this code more simple and more readable.

Comment: Please add your link as an answer. btw: I think it is unworthy for a GUI lib like Gtk to force the user to spin such a widget by her/himself!

Comment: I think it's awkward the default behavior of a spinner is to not spin. But who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject

class TreeView(Gtk.TreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        # model
        self.model = Gtk.ListStore.new([bool, int])
        for i in range(5):
            self.model.append([random.choice([True, True, False]), i])

        # view
        Gtk.TreeView.__init__(self, self.model)

        # column bool (as spinner)
        self.spinner_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererSpinner()
        col_bool = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('bool', self.spinner_renderer, active=0)
        self.append_column(col_bool)

        # column int
        col_int = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('int', Gtk.CellRendererText(), text=1)
        self.append_column(col_int)

    def on_spinner_pulse(self):
        for row in self.model:
            if row[0]:
                if row[1] == 150:
                    row[1] = 0
                else:
                    row[1] += 1
        self.spinner_renderer.set_property("pulse", row[1])
        return True

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='CellRendererSpinner')
        self.set_default_size(200, 400)

        self.view = TreeView()
        self.add(self.view)

        self.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Window()
    GObject.timeout_add(100, win.view.on_spinner_pulse)
Gtk.main()
```

> increment the Gtk.CellRendererSpinner :pulse property at regular intervals

1. Increase "pulse" value of cellrendererspinner by calling `self.spinner_renderer.set_property("pulse", newValue)` in a method
2. Call that method repeatedly with `GObject.timeout_add(milliseconds, method)` function

Comment: Why is there the `pulse` limit of `150`? Where in the docs are this limit?

Comment: Your code works fine. But please add more then two columns and there are problems: Sometimes they spin, sometimes they don't. I expanded your code to explain this https://gist.github.com/buhtz/81526447695fa7dc7d31259e8617aff1

Comment: The limt 150 is just a random value I choose. If you change the line `row[1] += 1` t o`row[1] += -1`. You will see a warning issued, `OverflowError: -1 not in range 0 to 4294967295`.

Comment: When they don't spin (in my gist-example code) it depends on some drawing issues. It is hard to reproduce. But when I move the mouse they spin.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work sometimes. I translate this program to D programming language. It always spins(even for 10 rows). https://gist.github.com/mywtfmp3/0ded49c3646b2dddcc098c782cfef7e5

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/CellRendererSpinner.html#Gtk.CellRendererSpinner):

> To start the animation in a cell, set the Gtk.CellRendererSpinner :active property to True and increment the Gtk.CellRendererSpinner :pulse property at regular intervals. The usual way to set the cell renderer properties for each cell is to bind them to columns in your tree model using e.g. Gtk.TreeViewColumn.add_attribute().

Comment: _increment ... :pulse property at regular intervals_? What does it mean in code? I have to spin it manualy? I imagine an on/off switch like `active`.